# Identify the degree , Minutes and seconds from coordinates

Tags: geojson, latitude-longitude, format

I have coordinates which has degree format, i want to convert it into decimal format,
For this i want to grab Degree , Minutes and seconds from coordinates.

Standard format is DDMMSS N / DDMMSS E , But i have one special type of  coordinates.

The coordinate is :

```
4729N00937E , 472027N0114441E , 472116N0114328E , 4729N00937E
```

I wan to convert it into decimal format ,  I want to use in Geojson.

Comment: Where are these coordinates from?  What have you tried?

Comment: This coordinates are third party API, found from http://notaminfo.com/

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.  Potential answerers do not always have time to go through comment trails before deciding whether to look for another question to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already stated in your comment, these are coordinates from a NOTAM (Notice To Airmen). The values are already in degree, minute and seconds using the format DDMMSSNDDDMMSSE or DDMMNDDDMME.

See also the following examples:

```
472027N0114441E --> 47°20'27''N 011°44'41''E
```

In case the seconds are zero, these are ommitted from the notation:

```
4729N00937E --> 47°29'00''N 009°37'00''E
```

Comment: These are the standard format for NOTAM ? is there any other format available or only this 2 format are used?

Comment: There is also the possibility to have only one coordinate with a radius (in nautical miles). And it's also not necessary that a NOTAM has extra coordinates at all mentioned, in case e.g. a whole flight information region (FIR) or airport is affected. However I am no expert in this topic, so you might get a more profound answer over at https://aviation.stackexchange.com/ regarding this new question.